HC-05 Can't change role to master
Do you know how to change role of the HC-05 to master role. I tried: AT+ROLE = 1
19:08:24.897 -> OK

But i chekced it and it it is still as slave (Role = 0)
19:08:26.792 -> +ROLE:0
19:08:26.792 -> OK
19:10:22.965 -> +ROLE:0

Do you know how to repair it ?

According to this documentation you need to "Connect the PIO11 to low level, repower the module," before it will switch to master mode. Did you do that?

@pmacfarlane Sure, i did it but still go no response after chaning the role

Some changes require that you reset the device before they take affect - I believe that the role is one of them. You can do this via AT+RESET.

HC-05 with firmware 2.0 tutorial

